# Indenting fold text

Tags: vim, folding

When you unfold nested levels of your code the folded text in nested code is not indented. It begins on the beginning of the line with `+` instead of starting indented.

Do you know how to change it?

[image: illustrating picture]

Comment: come again? I'll try to figure out what you mean, but it seems overly cryptic as written

Comment: I think he means that Vim's default foldtext is not indented, and he wants it be indented at the same level as its contents. But I wouldn't swear to that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the fold text to be indented at the same level as the first line of the fold, you need to prepend the indent level to the foldtext:

```
function! MyFoldText()
    let indent_level = indent(v:foldstart)
    let indent = repeat(' ',indent_level)
    ...
    ...   
    return indent . txt
endfunction
```

Here I am assuming that the string `txt` is your existing foldtext, so all you need to do is add it to the end of `indent`.

But I am not sure if that is what you want to achieve.

**EDIT:**

Now I have seen your picture, I'm not sure if this is what you want. You could try stripping the leading whitespace before appending to the `+`. So the foldtext you want will be something like `indent . '+' . txt`.

Maybe.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted. Only delete getline, from your snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the getline now.

Comment: For others looking this up, `foldtext()` is the function which returns the default foldtext. So `return indent.foldtext()` will return the default foldtext used but indented. Also, you need to type `let foldtext=MyFoldText()` somewhere for this custom function to be used.

Comment: just a tip for a special case: when I tried this using just getline(v:foldstart) in place of txt, the indentation was still a little off--the getline was adding 1 space per tab for some reason so I had to strip leading whitespace. Last line of the function now reads: `return indent . substitute(getline(v:foldstart),'^\s*','','')`

Answer (score 1):

Aha

You might want to comment out this function in your .vimrc:

```
set foldtext=MyFoldText()
set fillchars=fold:_
```

This is what makes your fold text appearing non default, by using the function:

```
function! MyFoldText()
  " setting fold text
  let nl = v:foldend - v:foldstart + 1
  let comment = substitute(getline(v:foldstart),"^ *\" *","",1)
  let linetext = substitute(getline(v:foldstart+1),"^ *","",1)
  let txt = '+ ' . comment . ': ' . nl .  ' ' . v:foldstart . '                                                                                                                                                                  '
  return txt
endfunction
```

As it happens, I quite like that function, but of course, de gustibus...

Comment: I'm glad you like it. This function advised me some guru from this forum (in another question). btw. that means "de gustibus"?

Comment: ... non est disputandum ([google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=non+est+disputandum))