# Gvim folding on system verilog keyword pairs

Tags: editor, system-verilog, vim

How do I enable folding on system verilog keywords in Gvim ?
For example

```
function
   Code
   ....
   ....
endfunction
```

I would like Gvim to create a fold from function to endfunction. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a custom foldexpression that should do what you want. It starts a fold on the line following each "function", and ends it on the line preceding each "endfunction", and otherwise inherits the foldlevel of the previous line.

```
function! VimFunctionFoldExpr()
    if getline(v:lnum-1) =~ '^\s*function'
        return '>1'
    elseif getline(v:lnum+1) =~ '^\s*endfunction'
        return '<1'
    else
        return '='
    endif
endfunction
```

To tell Vim to use this function, set the following:

```
set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=VimFunctionFoldExpr()
```

You might also want to tweak your foldtext setting so that it respects the intent level. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992336/indenting-fold-text) is a SE question about how to do that.

Comment: Is there a way I can ask vim to jump across these keywords ? Just like `{` `}` ?